# I wrote this code for inserting the values from the list to the mysql database and I got programming error

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
import mysql.connector
dbb_connection MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="root",database="translation",use_unicode=True,charset="utf8")
    dbb_cursor = dbb_connection.cursor()
    for item in eels:
        print(item)
        student_sql_query = ("INSERT INTO eng (Eng) VALUES %s" % (item))
        dbb_cursor.execute(student_sql_query)
        dbb_connection.commit()
        print(dbb_cursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted")
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'annual report january, 2018 – march, 2019 ministry of tourism government of in' at line 1")

Comment: Thou shalt not use `%` on SQL queries!

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. The syntax error is caused by missing parentheses:

```
student_sql_query = ("INSERT INTO eng (Eng) VALUES (%s)" % (item))
```

So, if `item` were an integer, say `7`, your SQL query would become:

```
INSERT INTO eng (Eng) VALUES (7)
```

But what if item were the string, `'boat'`? Then you would have:

```
INSERT INTO eng (Eng) VALUES (boat)
```

That is clearly wrong. So you knew that you had string values, you would be tempted to do the following:

```
student_sql_query = ("INSERT INTO eng (Eng) VALUES ('%s')" % (item))
```

And that might work, unless `item` had single quotes in it. But there is a bigger problem. If the value for `item` were user supplied, you could be exposed to a SQL Injection attack (look this up). The way you should be doing your query is as follows:

```
student_sql_query = "INSERT INTO eng (Eng) VALUES (%s)"
dbb_cursor.execute(student_sql_query, (item,))
```

Use `%s` as placeholders for your values in the SQL query and then pass either a `list` or a `tuple` containing the actual values to be substituted for the placeholders on the call to `execute`.